# ios Facebook login : com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason = invalid_client

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, client

I've been testing my FB app with my ios App for quite some time, using sandbox app and my admin account only; it worked fine.

Now, i've disabled sandbox mode in my fb app to have some of my FB friends test the application.

Whenever they try to connect from the iPhone app, they get the following display :

"myApp misconfigured for Facebook login"

and the error is : com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason = invalid_client  (error 2)

can't find any information about it anywhere.

Also (don't know if it matters), i don't use the Facebook native app on my iPhone (so i login through Safari), whereas my friends do (and get the error from Facebook native app).

Comment: i've just installed the Facebook native app on my iPhone and got the same error...definitely related...

Comment: you should verify your facebook app settings and make sure it is configured correctly to work with SSO. Specifically that you have set the "Configured for iOS SSO" option to Enabled and have the correct ios bundle id in place

Comment: Hi, thx for your comment. As far as i know, my configuration is correct : in iOS i have the URL identifier and URL schemes properly set, in my facebook app configuration page, i've enabled SSO (not native deep linking), my iOS bundle ID is correct (com.myCompany.myApp — i assume it's what i'm supposed to fill in) as well as the App Store ID. Still : works when i login from safari, fails when i login from Facebook native iOS app...

Comment: Maybe the problem is elsewhere; for now, the application (the Facebook application) has not yet been submitted to the facebook App Center; is it possible that's what's failing in Facebook native app ?

Comment: Got it.

It was indeed a misconfiguration.

Just so that it might help anyone with the same issue :
When you configure your app setting in Facebook, the Bundle ID you provide is the same as in your iPhone app.

Just make sure you write it properly, because :
- if you use it for login with the facebook native app, it is case-sensitive;
- if you use it for login with safari, it is case-insensitive.

Ergo didn't work through the native app since i had my case wrong.

Thanks Amir Naor (and Chana Tovah, may i add) for the guidance...

Comment: I can confirm i had this issue when i switched over the bundle ID and forgot to propagate the change to Facebook config on there site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bruce answered its own question in comments, I would provide it in a real answer.

The Facebook app bundle ID must be exactly the same than the iOS app bundle ID. If you've recently changed your bundle ID, or event your target name (by default the `product name` is set to `$(TARGET_NAME)` and the `bundle ID` to `${PRODUCT_NAME}`), this could be the cause of your problem.
Be careful, because bundle ID is case sensitive!

Finally, it could also be the Facebook App Configuration `namespace` field. My client did fill it with the application name, and that was the error. Leaving it empty resolved my problem.

Comment: This solution solved my similar, but different problem as well.  Xcode was appending ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} in my bundle id, which, when authenticating via the Facebook App, would return a login failure category of FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled.  But authenticating via Mobile Safari worked fine.

Comment: @Haseeb you can create your app in itunes connect, and, even if still not submitted, get its store id.